# google maps providing directions in local language

Tags: google-maps

I noticed that Google maps is providing directions in my local language (hungarian) when I am using google chrome, but English language directions when I am using it from IE.

I would like to know how chrome figures this out and how can I write code that is always returning directions on the user's language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTTP`requests` include an **Accept-Language header** which is set according to your locale preferences on most OS/browser combinations. Google uses a combination of that, the local domain you use (eg 'google.it', 'google.hu') and any preferences you set with the Preferences link in the home page to assign a language to your pages.

It's likely that IE is misrepresenting your locale to Google Maps, whereas Chrome has correctly guessed it. You can change IE's locale by changing your national settings in Control Panel, while Chrome's locale can be changed in (wrench menu) > Preferences.

Answer (score -1):

I could be way off but I think it's fairly safe to assume that google, is using gears.